# CONCAT or CONCATINATE

Tags: sql

Why do we need CONCATENATE if we have CONCAT function? Do they both play similar? I tried to use both, but I found error in CONCAT when CONCATENATE ran the function properly with clear answer.

I am trying to collect together multiple text strings alongs with spaces between one text string to another but I got error with CONCAT

Comment: Please edit your question and add your full queries, some simple data and the expected output, Also tag the RDBMS you are using

Comment: Are any null values concatenated?

Comment: What DBMS are you talking about? I don't know any that features a function called `CONCATENATE`.

Comment: "but I found error in CONCAT" - What error? Did you get an error message? If so, which? Or unexpected results? Then what result did you expect, what result did you get, what was your data and query?

Comment: There is some redundancy in functions because SQL standards have changed over time. DBMS's will add features to stay consistent with the standard or improve portability of queries across other DBMS's.

Answer (score 2):

The ANSI SQL (standard) concatenation operator is `||` for example

```
SELECT fname || ' ' || lname FROM mytable
```

Not all databases support this operator despite being a standard, some of them do not have it enabled by default. Many of them support the `CONCAT` function instead of or in addition to the `||` operator

```
SELECT CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) FROM mytable
```

So the answer to your question depends on what implementation of SQL (Oracle, postgres, mysql etc) you are using.

Comment: CONCAT function is also a part of SQL ISO standard. But the differences remains on the fact that || returns NULL on NULL input and concatenate only strings while CONCAT replace NULLs by a zero lengtht string and converts automaticllay all datatypes into strings based on ISO SQL default conversion format LIKE 'AAAA-MM-JJ' for dates...